# Restrict the Input in GWT TextInputCell

Tags: gwt

I need to Restrict the user input TextInputCell , 
For example i should be able to restrict the user to enter only 5 character in a TextInputCell. Pleas suggest the methods available to acheive this..

Regards,
Shiava

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First, you can restrict the user from typing in more than 5 characters:

```
myCell.getInputElement().setMaxLength(5);
```

Second, you can check the length of a user input and warn a user if it's too long. For example, if you use this cell in a column:

```
myColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Object, String>() {
    @Override
    public void update(int index, Object object, String value) {
        if (value.length() > 5) {
            // Warn user
        } else {
            object.setValue(value);
        }
    }
});
```